# UserManager<XYZ>' does not contain a definition for 'CreateIdentityAsync' and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net mvc core 2.1 version and I am receiving these two errors while adding properties in ApplicationUser Class
and I am receiving error on this piece of code :

```
 var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

I am trying to fix it from last 3 days Errors are :

> 'UserManager' does not contain a definition for 'CreateIdentityAsync' and no accessible extension method 'CreateIdentityAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'UserManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

"The name 'DefaultAuthenticationTypes' does not exist in the current context"

My Class are given below

```
 public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {


       public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public string FullName { set; get; }

        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        public int StateId { get; set; }

        public int CityId { set; get; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: `CreateIdentityAsync` is an ASP.NET MVC 5 method, it doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core. I think `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>.CreateUserPrincipalAsync` would do what you want.

Comment: I want to add some properties in my AspNetUser table. But I am stuck in this error.

Comment: I have the same question, stuck this error by 3 days - "The name 'DefaultAuthenticationTypes' does not exist in the current context". Please someone help.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you need to generate a `ClaimsIdentity` within the `ApplicationUser` entity, which is supposed to be a `POCO`. As far as I can see, it's better to move it somewhere else.

If you do want to add a method for this `Entity`, there're several ways to do that

1. As suggested by [@Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) in the comment, you could use the `SigninManager<ApplicationUser>.CreateUserPrincipalAsync()` to do that.
2. Another way is to use the [`IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserclaimsprincipalfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1) service to create a `ClaimsPrincipal` and then get the identity.

   ```
   var principal = _userClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(TUser user);
   // ... now we have the principal.Claims 
   // ... now we have the principal.Identity
   ```
3. Finally, if you only want to generate an `ClaimsIdentity`, you don't need `UserManager` or `SigninManager` or `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>`. Simply new it [as  the ASP.NET Core Team does](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/Core/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L75-L93):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); 
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, this.UserName));
        // ... add other claims as you like.

        return identity;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync` doesn't get hit.

Comment: Note that `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>.CreateAsync(TUser user)` adds additional default claims that you won't get with `new ClaimsIdentity`. Thus the factory is the closest to the old UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync in Identity 2.1 (.NET Framework).